# Consolidating data from multiple fields to a single field

Tags: mysql, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

I have 2 tables with 1 to many relationship between them.
I need to consolidate data contained in 1 column in the 2nd table and add it to corresponding single entry in the first table.
How could I do that in MySQL ?

- ID is the primary key
  Example:

Table 2 **Calculation**

```
ID  Forms  Calc

1    A      20

1    B      30

1    C      10
```

Target Table :

Table1 **Client**

```
ID    Name     Forms

1     XYZ      A,B,C
```

Comment: It is generally a poor practice to store comma delimited lists in a field.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Client (ID, Forms)
SELECT ID , GROUP_CONCAT(Forms)
FROM Calculation
GROUP BY ID
```